# How do I change the color of raisedButton onPressed?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to change the color of the raisedButton when pressed, I have been having trouble with this for a while, the code I have right now for the whole button widget is

```
children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                      child: new SizedBox(
                        width: 15,
                        height: 60,
                        child: new RaisedButton(
                            color: pressed ? Color(0xFF1D1E33) : Colors.blue,
                            hoverColor: Colors.blueAccent,
                            focusColor: Colors.blueAccent,
                            child: Text(
                              'Male',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 26,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  color: Colors.white),
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            ),
                            onPressed: () => setState((){pressed = !pressed;})),
                      ),
```

I also had a boolean as shown below but I received an error when running the code saying "Failed assertion: boolean expression must not be null"

```
bool get pressed => null;

set pressed(bool pressed) {}
```

Comment: That's a pretty straightforward error message, don't set a boolean to null, set it to false, then change it to true when needed. Either you set the boolean value to false or true or you don't set it at all, just don't set it to null or any other thing.

Comment: You have to set value to 'pressed' first when you create it.

Comment: Use  `GestureDetector` instead of `RaisedButton`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
code snippet

```
  bool _pressed = false;

  bool get pressed {
    return _pressed;
  }

  set pressed(bool pressed) {
    _pressed = pressed;
  }
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;
  bool _pressed = false;

  bool get pressed {
    return _pressed;
  }

  set pressed(bool pressed) {
    _pressed = pressed;
  }

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
                child: new SizedBox(
                    width: 100,
                    height: 60,
                    child: new RaisedButton(
                        color: pressed ? Color(0xFF1D1E33) : Colors.blue,
                        hoverColor: Colors.blueAccent,
                        focusColor: Colors.blueAccent,
                        child: Text(
                          'Male',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 26,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              color: Colors.white),
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        ),
                        onPressed: () => setState(() {
                              pressed = !pressed;
                            })))),
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```